# Проблема видимости bash команд на AWS EC2

Tags: node.js, docker, amazon-web-services, circleci

Я занимаюсь построением системы continuous deployment на основе CircleCI, Docker и AWS. Для deploy написал скрипт, который упаковывает все исходники, потом передает их на сервер по SSH и там распаковывает. Далее, следует поднятие docker-compose. Сам docker-compose на сервере стоит, если запускать его вручную, заходя на сервер через терминал, то все работает, но при запуске из CircleCI пишет:

> ./build/deploy_to_master.sh: line 13: docker-compose: command not found

В чем может быть проблема того, что Circle, который заходит через SSH, не видит уже установленный compose?

Comment: Вызов предельно прост:
ssh ubuntu@IP_of_instance cd src; docker-compose up
src - папка,где лежит docker-compose.yml

Comment: Посмотрите в консоли на которой все работает чему равна PATH: `echo $PATH`. и такую же команду добавьте в ваш .sh скрипт и запустите его так, как он не работает. Думаю PATH в нем будет гораздо короче и он просто не видит всех каталогов с запускаемыми файлами. Если это так, добавьте в ваш .sh установку правильной переменной PATH. Возможно надо будет так же ставить еще какие то переменные окружения, посмотреть все переменные можно по `set`

Comment: @Mike Пожалуйста, опубликуйте ваш комментарий в виде ответа.

Answer (score 3):

Посмотрите в консоли на которой все работает чему равна PATH: `echo $PATH`.

И такую же команду добавьте в ваш .sh скрипт и запустите его в том виде, в котором он не работает. Думаю PATH в нем будет гораздо короче...

Шелл просто не видит всех каталогов с запускаемыми файлами. Если это так, добавьте в ваш .sh установку правильной переменной PATH. Возможно надо будет так же ставить еще какие то переменные окружения, посмотреть все переменные можно по команде `set`